# How to search multiple workbooks for Cell information - upgrade?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have these several huge Excel files, each with a lot of sheets. I have to manually search each of them for specific string and to check if it exists somewhere.

I have found the following code [here](https://superuser.com/questions/888295/excel-how-to-search-multiple-workbooks-for-cell-information) and so far it works.

```vb
Sub SearchFolders()
Dim fso As Object
Dim fld As Object
Dim strSearch As String
Dim strPath As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim wOut As Worksheet
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long
Dim rFound As Range
Dim strFirstAddress As String


On Error GoTo ErrHandler
Application.ScreenUpdating = False


'Change as desired
strPath = "c:\MyFolder"
strSearch = "Specific text"

Set wOut = Worksheets.Add
lRow = 1
With wOut
    .Cells(lRow, 1) = "Workbook"
    .Cells(lRow, 2) = "Worksheet"
    .Cells(lRow, 3) = "Cell"
    .Cells(lRow, 4) = "Text in Cell"
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set fld = fso.GetFolder(strPath)

    strFile = Dir(strPath & "\*.xls*")
    Do While strFile <> ""
        Set wbk = Workbooks.Open _
          (Filename:=strPath & "\" & strFile, _
          UpdateLinks:=0, _
          ReadOnly:=True, _
          AddToMRU:=False)

        For Each wks In wbk.Worksheets
            Set rFound = wks.UsedRange.Find(strSearch)
            If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
                strFirstAddress = rFound.Address
            End If
            Do
                If rFound Is Nothing Then
                     lRow = lRow + 1
                    .Cells(lRow, 1) = wbk.Name
                    .Cells(lRow, 2) = wks.Name
                    .Cells(lRow, 3) = rFound.Address
                    .Cells(lRow, 4) = rFound.Value
Else
Exit Do

                End If
                Set rFound = wks.Cells.FindNext(After:=rFound)
            Loop While strFirstAddress <> rFound.Address
        Next

            wbk.Close (False)
            strFile = Dir
        Loop
        .Columns("A:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
    MsgBox "Done"

ExitHandler:
    Set wOut = Nothing
    Set wks = Nothing
    Set wbk = Nothing
    Set fld = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation
    Resume ExitHandler
End Sub
```

But in order to search for a string, every time I have to open the code and change the path and the search word:

```
strPath = "c:\MyFolder"            
strSearch = "Specific text"
```

Instead of opening the code and changing the path each timе, I would like somehow to have a search field or something like this on the picture attached. Is it possible?

[image]

Or for example two cells on the sheet with the results, where I can put the path and the search word, without opening the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
strPath = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").value 
strSearch = ActiveSheet.Range("B1").value
```

To make the buttons, add form controls using the developer ribbon.

Comment: strPath = ActiveSheet.Range("A1") 
strSearch = ActiveSheet.Range("B1")

It says that Object is required.. Is it because I have set strPath as String in the beginning? Something is not right...

Comment: or "Object variable or With block variable not set " 
I am sorry, I am quite new at this

Comment: Try .value property. Helpful hint, always hit the dot! You can many times guess the right property by just typing say  ...Range("A1")**.** which will show a list of methods and properties to scroll through.

Comment: I did it! It is working perfectly! :)